# Chrome Extension Development - POST to new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an easy solution to POST dynamically aggregated data into a new tab?

`chrome.tabs.create` does not have a 'POST' option. Normally I would use

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (t) {
  chrome.tabs.create(
  {
    "url" : "http://super.url",
    "method" : "POST" // oops.. no option.
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, the only solution I can think of is sending your dynamic data to the background file, creating a new tab which includes a form. Fill up the form using your form using the content using the background file, and then submit the form. Nothing else I can think of.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Do you know of any resources pointing to the exact solution you mention? First of all - manipulating new tab contents from the 'parent' tab.

Comment: It would take some time to learn, okay? Read up about [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) on Google's docs first. Then read up on [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#simple). After you've understood all of that, it'd be fairly simple to send a message from the script, to the background, and to the script of a different tab. I may be wrong with this, though, because there may exist a way through which 2 tabs can communicate without this hassle. Just ask if I've confused you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply combine these two techniques:

1. You may execute JavaScript commands by adding `javascript:` prefix at your address bar or in `href` values of `<a>` tags.
2. Only with JavaScript, you can create a form element and fill it with your data then POST it.

```js
function fakePost() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    
    // Create a POST dump at ptsv2.com and change the code
    form.setAttribute("action", "http://ptsv2.com/t/dcgex-1614815819/post");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");

    var params = { userId: 2, action: "delete" };
    for(var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    // Appending the form might not be necessary
    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
};

const 
    source = fakePost.toString().replace(/(\n|\t)/gm,'').replace(/\s\s/gm,' '),
    url = `javascript:${source}; fakePost();`;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => chrome.tabs.create({ url }));
```

Of course, that's just a dirty hack. If you need something more elaborate you can use a [XHR Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or @Xan's answer.

Comment: Beware! This answer should **not** be used for sensitive form data, because web pages can intercept and manipulate the form data that is inserted in this way.

Comment: @RobW it is just a sample for demo purpose...don't be serious, for those copy paste developer, they should bear the consequences.

Answer (score 19):

The code in cvsguimaraes' answer works for short data strings, that can fit into a URL.
As evidenced by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682827/send-text-with-post-method-from-chrome-extension/), it's not always the case.

Kenny Evitt's answer hints at the solution. I made an implementation for that question, and took time to generalize it. I present it here.

The idea is to open a page bundled with the extension (post.html), supply it with required information via messaging, and perform the POST from that page.

**post.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    <!-- Decorate as you wish, this is a page that redirects to a final one -->
    <script src="post.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**post.js**

```
var onMessageHandler = function(message){
  // Ensure it is run only once, as we will try to message twice
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(onMessageHandler);

  // code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7404033/934239
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", message.url);
  for(var key in message.data) {
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", message.data[key]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageHandler);
```

**background.js** (or other non-content script inside the extension)

```
function postData(url, data) {
  chrome.tabs.create(
    { url: chrome.runtime.getURL("post.html") },
    function(tab) {
      var handler = function(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if(tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status === "complete"){
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(handler);
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {url: url, data: data});
        }
      }

      // in case we're faster than page load (usually):
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handler);
      // just in case we're too late with the listener:
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {url: url, data: data});
    }
  );  
}

// Usage:
postData("http://httpbin.org/post", {"hello": "world", "lorem": "ipsum"});
```

Note the double messaging: with `chrome.tabs.create` callback we can't be sure that the listener is ready, nor can we be sure it's not done loading yet (though in my testing, it's always still loading). But better safe than sorry.

Comment: can you please inform me if post.js is a content script or popup script?

Comment: @senty Neither. It's a script in an extension page that's not a popup.

Comment: I got a bit confused. If I have a `.js` file added to my popup, should I use your `post.js` and call it in a function, and also setup `background.js` like you showed here? Or is this for a completely different approach?

Comment: This technique works well for me in Chrome and Firefox but I cannot get it to work in a Safari Web Extension. In background.js the handler is never called and the "just in case" sendMessage has no effect (and it gets an undefined response if I add a response to test it). I am able to make the send message work by adding an additional sendMessage after a 500ms timeout. But then inside post.js the post does not work. It does end up switching to the correct url (the one in the form action) but doesn't send any of the post data. Anyone figured out how to make this work in Safari?

Comment: Update to the previous comment. What actually made the sendMessage work in Safari was to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage rather than chrome.tabs.sendMessage. The documentation is confusing in that it says that tabs.sendMessage sends message to *content scripts* and it is not clear if a script loaded by an extension page is a content script. Chrome sends the message to it, Safari doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From @Amman Cheval's comments on the question:

> [send] your dynamic data to the background file, creating a new tab which includes a form. Fill up the form using your form using the content using the background file, and then submit the form.
>
> Read up about content scripts on Google's docs first. Then read up on message passing. After you've understood all of that, it'd be fairly simple to send a message from the script, to the background, and to the script of a different tab.