# Chrome Extension : How to Get a form and fill and submit it

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension where I need to get HTML from the website. It has a form which needs to be filled and submitted back.

I click the extension button, pop up opens. I enter details. It fetches me a website which has a form that needs to be filled and submitted back.
I currently am using tabs to open the URL, fill the form and submit it back, but I dont want the user to see all the happenings.

I also tried Ajax but not sure how exactly to get HTML, fill the inputs and submit it back.

I tried iFrames but then I get the Unsafe javascript error.
Not sure I want to use background page as it will be running in the background always.

Is there any way I can actually make it happen in the background?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) is an extension that allows you to do something similar, you can peek into its source to get some ideas.

Also see [Chrome Extension Development - POST to new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab) as the first answer shows you how to submit a fake form using JS.