# Javascript GET with name and id

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can't seem to work this out... I'm not actually sure whether it's even possible the way I'm trying. Basically- I'm building a Chrome extension to search my database for selected text. The database will only accept queries with an `id` and `name`.

Here is my `.js` file that I am calling:

```
function getword(info,tab) {
    console.log("Word " + info.selectionText + " was clicked.");
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
        url: "http://mydatabase.com/contacts" + info.selectionText,
    })
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({

    title: "Search database for '%s'", 
    contexts:["selection"], 
    onclick: getword,
});
```

An example of what my database would require to perform this search is:

```
<form action='http://mydatabase.com/contacts' target='_blank' autocomplete='off' method='post' novalidate>

<input id='Search_ContactName' name='Search.ContactName' type='hidden' value='". $row['COL 2'] . "' class='valid'>

<button class='button'>Find on MyDatabase</button></form>
```

Simply put, I need `info.selectionText` in the `.js` file above to have a `name` and `id` ... Then to `get` the query to `http://mydatabase.com/contacts`.

Unfortunately I think I've reached the limit of my knowledge on this one. Been Googling a lot and am starting to wonder if it is possible.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: `chrome.tabs.create` will issue a `GET` request, not a `POST` request. To `POST` it, you can either use ajax, or this technique - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab

Comment: Alternatively, you can reconfigure your `/contacts` script to accept `GET` parameters.

Comment: @levi My mistake- it will accept `GET` requests also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a form, only the field names and values are passed as parameters, not the id's. To add `info.selectionText` as a `GET` paramater, you should structure your URL like this:

```
url: "http://mydatabase.com/contacts?Search.ContactName=" + info.selectionText
```

Where `Search.ContactName` is the field name.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but I'd used the filter instead of search. Have no idea why! THANKS!