# Send text with post method from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension

**Send big text with chrome extension**.

I'm trying to send big text which is stored in my local storage to a site using my chrome extension. I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7404033)
and using this code

```
function ls(){return localStorage['txt'];}
function fakePost() {   
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "http://cvsguimaraes.altervista.org/fiddles/postcheck.php");
var params = {action: ls()};
for(var key in params) {
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
};
fakePostCode = fakePost.toString().replace(/(\n|\t)/gm,'');

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (t) {
chrome.tabs.create({"url" : "javascript:"+fakePostCode+"; fakePost();"});
});
```

but ls is not defined. How can I send this text? And I'm not using XmlHTTP because I need *to open it in new tab*

Comment: Deleted my answer, since I misread the answer you're linking to. Please include the relevant code in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the answer would be that you cannot use the described method. Your big data won't fit into an URL, and the code you inject via a URL has *no way at all* to interact with extension code.

You need an alternative solution, but thankfully it should be easy. You can include an html file into your extension that will post the data, and open that page instead. That HTML file, being part of your extension, has access to its `localStorage`.

**Edit: I've created a general solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab/23687543#23687543).**

Something along those lines:

post.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="post.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

post.js:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "http://cvsguimaraes.altervista.org/fiddles/postcheck.php");
var params = {action: localStorage['txt'];};
for(var key in params) {
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (t) {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url" : chrome.runtime.getURL("post.html")});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but you should load your script in post.html not in head but in body because when script loads in head it couldn't find body to append form

Comment: Thanks for catching that. When I get home, I'll generalize this method and put it as an answer for the original question.

Comment: I've created a general solution and posted it [at the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab/23687543#23687543). Thanks, it was an interesting problem.