# Create a link with POST data from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension that sends a POST request to some server and gets its response then displays an number badge according to the data.

Now I want to create a link inside the popup.html based on the data used to send the POST request to the server it self so the users can see the data on the website (data source).

This is the code I use in **popup.js** to send the POST request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://someserver/path', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function () {
    var regex = new RegExp(/ID:\d+/g);
    var testregex = regex.test(this.responseText);
    if (testregex == true) {
        var count = this.responseText.match(/ID:\d+/g).length;
        var countext = count.toString();
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: countext});
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "0"});
    }
};
getCurrentTabUrl(function(url) {
var cleanurl = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/i);
xhr.send('search=' + cleanurl[1] +'&submit=Search');
});
```

Question is how do I create a link with the same POST data I used before?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't get what your question is exactly? How to create a link in an HTML document from JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, using the same POST data that I used - meaning data could change in different tabs so it has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to query an external service, then display some information in the popup with a link to more information.

Let's make a scaffold of how you're going to display it. In your popup, include the following:

```
<div id="data-container">
  <div id="data-loading">
    <!-- Maybe add an animated spinner here, or something else -->
    Loading...
  </div>
  <div id="data-display">
    <!-- Currently empty, will add a link here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Style this as you wish. Then, from your XHR:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
  /* ... */

  // Hide the loading notice
  document.getElementById("data-loading").style.display = "none";

  // Create the element that will show more details;
  //  <a href="#"> works okay, but consider making a button
  var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = "#";
      link.text = "More details..." // Add data from xhr.responseText?
      link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

  var container = document.getElementById("data-display");

  // Make sure the container is empty (in case we're calling this again)
  while (container.lastChild) node.removeChild(container.lastChild);

  // Append more elements if you want to display some data
  container.appendChild(link);
};
```

Now the interesting part: the `clickHandler` click handler. To open a new tab from the popup, you should use `chrome.tabs.create()`:

```
function clickHandler() {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: /* ??? */
  });
}
```

It would be trivial if we wanted to open a normal GET page. To open a POST page, we have to cheat. There are two main possibilities:

1. Open a `javascript:` URL that performs a POST. Conceptually easier, but only works for short parameters.
2. Open a helper page in your extension that will perform POST. This allows you to pass arbitrarily large arguments before the POST happens.

Both are covered in this question: [Chrome Extension Development - POST to new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7387217/934239)