# Firefox extension open page using POST

Tags: firefox, post, content-security-policy

In Firefox extension I need to open a specific webpage in new tab and I need to send POST data to it. I have full control over target webpage (my server).

What I've tried so far is..

This is actually sending GET with no data (but works in Chrome. Possibly a CSP limitation..)
[Chrome Extension Development - POST to new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab)

Instead of using generated FORM on the webpage, i tried XmlHttpRequest. I can successfully send the post request and get the answer, but I only get the response as plain text and can't open it in current window (I only get static content without working scripts upon inserting it to the page's BODY)

I played with the XHR response a bit and tried:

```
document.open();
document.write(xhr.responseText);
```

but I get "Loading of source self ("script-src") was blocked due to CSP".

So I tried to find the answer how to set CSP and headers and I inserted a header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
```

on both local and the remote page. It did not help, though.

Does anyone know a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

When you add `"script-src 'self'` you are allowing script files to be accessed within the same domain, but inline-scripts (as in `<script> ... </script>`) will still be disallowed.

To allow inline scripts, you can add the `'unsafe-inline'` part after `'self'`. But this is not recommended, because it defeats a large part of what CSP is trying to do (prevent XSS attacks). You should add a base64 sha256 hash of each inline script instead (assuming it is a static unchanging script) with the `sha256` prefix. e.g. `'sha256-xxxxORCihnocralsomehashgoeshere'`).

However, if you aren't using inline scripts, maybe the browser is smart enough to know that the script you're running came from a different domain and is blocking it. If so, try adding the specific domain in the request on your requesting page. For instance, if you are posting to 'example.com', your CSP will look like this:

`content="script-src 'self' 'example.com'"`

Finally, You should know that the preferred CSP mechanism is by HTTP Header, and some browsers may not support it. It also has additional restrictions in that it can't be used in frame-ancestors and can't hook up to report-uri.